# How to make flattened stream of streams hot and connectible in RX.Net?

Tags: system.reactive, .net-7.0, rx.net

I have a reactive emitter that aggregates sources. When a source is added or removed it emits a new collection of observables in a stream. I use this to flatten it out.

`stream.Select(e => e.Merge()).Switch();`

That's working just fine for subscribers that come before any addition or removal, as they get the new aggregated stream. But I did not manage to make this connectible (hot), so that anybody subscribing at any point in time gets subscribed to the latest aggregated stream.

Even if I add `.Publish()` and `AutoConnect()` the result is the same.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] of what you've done so far? What is a "reactive emitter that aggregates sources"?